# Replace atom with variable

Tags: prolog

I have a term which may or may not contain the atom 'this'. The term may also contain variables.
I need to replace 'this' with a variable I. How can I do this?
I tried to do something like this:

```
term_to_atom((f(a), g(this, b), ...), A),

tokenize_atom(A, L),

replace(this, I, L, L2)
```

It seemed to work. The problem is, I need to go back to the original term and I can't do it...

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog has [atomic_list_concat/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/2) and [atom_to_term/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_to_term/3) which should help you go back to the original term.

```
main :-
    term_to_atom((f(a), g(this, b)), A),
    tokenize_atom(A, L),
    replace(this, 'I', L, L2),
    atomic_list_concat(L2, A2),
    atom_to_term(A2, T, []),
    writeln(T).

?- main.
f(a),g(_G69,b)
true .
```

Comment: atomic_list_concat doesn't work. I think it's because the term may also contain variables and atomic_list_concat needs a list of atoms.

Comment: You probably want `replace(this, 'I', L, L2)` so that your list of atoms contains the atom 'I'.  Then `atomic_list_concat` should work.  I've updated my answer to show a complete example.

Comment: it works, but when I assert the term as the body of a rule, it sets the variables as _, and I need it to keep the name.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this predicate (replace/4):

```
replace(Term,Term,With,With) :-
    !.
replace(Term,Find,Replacement,Result) :-
    Term =.. [Functor|Args],
    replace_args(Args,Find,Replacement,ReplacedArgs),
    Result =.. [Functor|ReplacedArgs].

replace_args([],_,_,[]).
replace_args([Arg|Rest],Find,Replacement,[ReplacedArg|ReplacedRest]) :-
    replace(Arg,Find,Replacement,ReplacedArg),
    replace_args(Rest,Find,Replacement,ReplacedRest).
```

An example of what you need:

```
| ?- replace(f(1,23,h(5,this)),this,Var,Result).                                                                                           

Result = f(1,23,h(5,Var))                                                                                                                  

yes
```

Comment: You can also replace subterms using a predicate like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145013/975097).