# Prolog - replacing subterms

Tags: recursion, prolog, universal

I'm doing some past exam papers for practice for my exam, and I've come across a question that I'm not quite sure how to tackle:

[image]

I know I've got to use the "univ" function to break up the term into a list, and then recurse through that list and check if any of the elements in the list equal the term we want to replace. However, I'm a bit lost with double recursing when the list contains another complex term that we have to break down further. My attempt so far is as follows:

```
complexTerm(X) :- nonvar(X), functor(X, _, A), A > 0.

replace(Term, Subterm, Subterm1, Term1) :-
    Term =.. [H|T],
    replaceSub([H|T], Subterm, Subterm1, Term1)

replaceSub([], Subterm, Subterm1, Term1).
replaceSub([H], Subterm, Subterm1, Term1) :- 
    atomic(X),
    H == Subterm, 
    H = Subterm1.
replaceSub([H], Subterm, Subterm1, Term1) :-
    complexTerm(H),
    replace(H, Subterm, Subterm1, Term1).
replaceSub([H|T]) :- % not sure where to continue with this.
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Note that for the exam we can't use external modules.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Double-recursing isn't required here.  replace can simply check all the term types and deal with complex terms by recursing into itself.  Just watch that you don't have the =.. case handle the list case.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Sorry, I meant double recursing as in recursing into itself. That's the step I'm unsure of. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The key to such tasks is to recognize *which cases you actually need to distinguish*.

As it turns out: Not many.

For example:

```
replace(Subterm0, Subterm, Term0, Term) :-
        (   Term0 == Subterm0 -> Term = Subterm
        ;   var(Term0) -> Term = Term0
        ;   Term0 =.. [F|Args0],
            maplist(replace(Subterm0,Subterm), Args0, Args),
            Term =.. [F|Args]
        ).
```

I have taken the small liberty to use an argument order that makes `maplist/3` applicable.

To quote from the Prolog standard:

> ```
> 8.5.3 (=..)/2 - univ
>
> 8.5.3.1 Description
>
> '=..'(Term, List) is true iff:
>
>   - Term is an atomic term and List is the list whose
>   only element is Term, or
>   ...
> ```

For this reason, *atomic and complex terms can be handled uniformly* in this case! There is no reason to distinguish between atomic and complex terms, nor is there any reason to treat lists specially in any way.

Example:

```
?- replace(1, 2, f(a,[[b]],g(1),X,h(z,1)), T).
T = f(a, [[b]], g(2), X, h(z, 2)).
```

Comment: In some cases, this predicate does not replace the input pattern with the output pattern. `replace(A+B,A-B,(2+3),Result)` unifies `Result` with `2+3` instead of `2-3`.

Comment: It seems to work as expected in this case, because `A+B` is not a subterm of `2+3`, is it?

Comment: `replace(2, 1, T0, f(a,[[b]],g(1),X,h(z,1))).` produces only one answer, the first of several that it is required to produce by the task description in the picture.